# dangerouslySetInnerHTML returns [object, object] with any input that contains markup (eg 'a', 'div', 'span', etc)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, custom-component, ionic-react

I've created a custom component that is used simply for display purposes:

```
import React from 'react';
import './CardContainer.css';
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';

interface ContainerProps {
    content?: any,
    children?: any;
}

const CardContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ content = "n/a", children }) => {
    
    //children override content if populated for backwards compatibility
    let sanitise = "";
    children ? sanitise = children : sanitise = content;

    const clean = sanitizeHtml(sanitise, {
        allowedTags: ['b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a', 'div', 'span', 'svg', 'IonIcon', 'icon', 'ion-icon'],
        allowedAttributes: {
          a: ['href', 'target'],
          div: ['class', 'className'],
          span: ['style', 'class', 'className']
        }
    });



  return <><div color={colour} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: clean}}/><div>clean</div></>
};

export default CardContainer;
```

If I send plain text into it, there is no problem. But if the `content` or `children` contains any sort of html tags, the content of those tags is returned as `[object, object]`.

I've done some testing and it seems that if `content` or `children` are passed through `sanitizeHtml` or `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` this is always the result.

So for example the following is what I get if I play around with the return statement in my Cardcontainer.

The following always result in `[object, object]`

```
return <div color={colour} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: clean}}/>
return <div color={colour} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: children}}/>
return <div color={colour} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitize}}/>

return <div>clean</div>
return <div>sanitize</div>
```

However, the following renders as expected.

```
return <div>children</div>
```

I'm evidently missing something here, but I'm totally confused at this point as it seems both `sanitizeHtml` and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` are having the same impact on the the passed in content regardless of whether it's done as a variable or as children.